# How to extract the result of a query with JDBC in a CSV

Tags: java, csv, jdbc, jar

I'm looking for an easy way of dumping a SQL query result in a readable way through command line. I have to do that for all sort of database (oracle, mysql, sybase, postgres...) so I'm using JDBC. I need the dump file to be on my local computer (not the server).

I have a main java archive with all the drivers and usually when I connect to a database with JDBC (through python), I need to specify the path to the driver and the driver class.

The goal is to run something like

```
<tool> <jdbc-URL> <driver location> <driver class> <login> <pwd> <query> <output file>
```

Using a java archive for instance

```
java Tool.jar 'jdbc:sybase:db.com:11/sys'        # <jdbc-URL>
              'path/to/JDBCsybaseDriver.jar'     # <driver location>
              'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver'  # <driver class>
              'root' ''                          # <login> <pwd>
              'SELECT * FROM <tab> WHERE <cond>' # <query>
              'output.csv'                       # <output file>
```

And to get a proper csv file

```
PID;Name;IsDead
144;Mike;True
266;Carl;False
984;Anna;False
```

Do you know any tool that could do that?

I don't know how I could write this myself and I'm not very familiar with java so if you come up with some code, please provides explanation on how to build it into a executable java archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic application to write the output of a SQL query to a ;-separated file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SqlOut {

    public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String pw) throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", user);
        connectionProps.put("password", pw);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProps);
        return conn;
    }

    private static String coalesce(Object o, String nullValue)
    {
        if(o==null)
            return nullValue;
        return o.toString();
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * [0] : jdbc connection url
     * [1] : JDBC driver class name
     * [2] : database user
     * [3] : database password
     * [4] : SQL statement
     * [5] : output file name
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName(args[1]);
        Connection conn = getConnection(args[0], args[2], args[3]);
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(args[4]);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = rs.getMetaData();
        File outfile=new File(args[5]);
        try (FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(new File(args[5]))) {
            // export column names
            for (int ci = 1; ci <= rsmeta.getColumnCount(); ci++) {
                if (ci > 1)
                    fos.write(";");
                fos.write(rsmeta.getColumnLabel(ci));
            }
            fos.write("\n");
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int ci = 1; ci <= rsmeta.getColumnCount(); ci++) {
                    if(ci > 1)
                        fos.write(";");
                    fos.write(coalesce(rs.getObject(ci),""));
                }
                fos.write("\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("CSV file written to "+outfile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

The code contains no dependencies other then java runtime and it has no package declaration so it can be easily compiled:

```
DOS> javac SqlOut.java
```

assuming you have a Java JDK avaiable in your classpath.

The driver jar must be available in the classpath at the moment you launch the application so you pass it through the classpath, not as an argument to the application.

The command to call this (from DOS prompt):

```
DOS> java -classpath .;\path\to\driver.jar SqlOut jdbc:db:serverurl org.postgresql.Driver user pw "select * from myTable where 1=1" out.csv
```

Do not put quotes arround the arguments except for the SQL statement as it contains spaces.
On unix the classpath separator is : instead of ;

EDIT: fixed separator for the header line: , replcaed by ;

Comment: Thank you!! I'll try this and accept the answer when I get it to work

Comment: What happens if `rs.getObject(ci)` returns a String that contains a semicolon, e.g., `"TL;DR"` ? Also, why is the first row (column headers) delimited by commas while the subsequent rows (data) are delimited by semicolons?

Comment: Probably a typo. I'll add the separator to the arguments. What's the best way of dealing with a separator appearing in values?

Comment: Ok so I got it to work almost instantly (thank you for your explanations!!). I'll play around with the separator but other than that, it's perfect, thank you!!